# Excel Conversion to CSV

Tags: groovy

I am picking some excel files and converting them to CSV using Groovy script.
The script is able to convert it into CSV but it is skipping null values at the record level.
Ex. Let's say a file has 5 columns, one of the records has a null value for 3rd column, so the script is skipping that value and will map 4th value under the 3rd column.

Can you please help with the problem.

Thanks
Nupur

Comment: How do you expect us to help you without seeing your code?

Comment: I guess that `null` values aren't saved in xlsx and that you have to get the column index from the current cell. You cannot use the the iterating index or just assume that every row iterator will fill up empty cells. 

As mentioned before: This is just a guess, bc I don't know your excel access lib (may be apache-poi) and I don't know how you iterate over the rows.

Answer (score 1):

You are giving us very little detail to be able to answer your question. What external libraries are you using? How does your code look? What calls are you making? What version and format of excel are you reading? Etc etc.

In other words, please make an effort to include as much information as possible when posting a question here.

With that said, the most common way to read excel from java/groovy is [apache poi](https://poi.apache.org/) and if you are using apache poi, you normally end up doing something like this:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*

// skipping code for opening the workbook and getting a row from it
def cell  = row.getCell(cellIndex) 

// either using data formatter 
def dataFormatter = new DataFormatter(Locale.US)
def value1 = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell)

// or directly if you know the cell type
def value2 = cell.stringCellValue
```

if you are doing this, you end up with exactly the behavior you describe, i.e. null cell values skewing the indexing of cells. You can get around this by specifying a [MissingCellPolicy](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.MissingCellPolicy.html) as in:

```
def cell = row.getCell(cellIndex, Row.MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK)
```

Then again, as you gave us basically no information chances are this answer might be totally irrelevant.